# Why HBase client put object expecting at least a column to be added, before submitting?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

As the hbase Support flexible schema and my usecase needs the qualifier is dynamic value and available only on some logic (if true add column else skip) in this case we are expecting put execution should be OK even without adding any columns to it.

But we are end up of getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No columns to insert
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.validatePut(HTable.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.validatePut(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:152)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.mutate(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:127)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:1028)

```
Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey"))
if(condition1){
p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"),Bytes.toBytes("Q1")
}
table.put(p)
```

Comment: Referring to HBase client soure code public static void validatePut(Put put, int maxKeyValueSize) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (put.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No columns to insert");
    } , We are filterout the put objects without columns from execution.

Answer (score 0):

All HBase data has to be associated with a column family, even if nothing else is populated. In your case, if `!condition1` then you simply shouldn't write anything:

```
if(condition1){
    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey"))
    p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"),Bytes.toBytes("Q1")
    table.put(p)
 }
```

Comment: Yes, we are end up doing the same. Although we have many other business conditions around columns addition to put object. We restricting the execution just by if(!p.isEmpty()) at end all business conditions.

Comment: The code you've pasted clearly shows the potential for a blank `put` to be inserted into a table. The error you've pasted clearly shows that is happening. The error must be within you code that you're not showing here.